# Modify spi node in beagleboneblack device tree

Tags: driver, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I'm trying to make beaglebone black work with **ATWILC1000** wifi chip. This chip uses SPI and I have to modify `SPI` node in `am33xx.dtsi` file in order to make the provided driver work. I'm using debian with **4.14.71-ti-r80** kernel.

I'm following [the guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATWILC1000-ATWILC3000-ATWILC-Devices-Linux-Porting-Guide-User-Guide-DS70005329C.pdf) provided by microchip.

I've added some code to the `am33xx.dtsi` `SPI1` node as indicated in the guide in order to specify which pin will be used by the driver.

Here is the node I modified, I added the part from `wilc_spi@0 {` :

```
spi@481a0000 {
                    compatible = "ti,omap4-mcspi";
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x0>;
                    reg = <0x481a0000 0x400>;
                    interrupts = <0x7d>;
                    ti,spi-num-cs = <0x2>;
                    ti,hwmods = "spi1";
                    dmas = <0x2d 0x2a 0x0 0x2d 0x2b 0x0 0x2d 0x2c 0x0 0x2d 0x2d 0x0>;
                    dma-names = "tx0", "rx0", "tx1", "rx1";
                    status = "disabled";

                    wilc_spi@0 {
                            cs-gpios = <0x3d 0x11 0x3>;
                            reset-gpios = <0x38 0x1a 0x7>;
                            chip_en-gpios = <0x3e 0xc 0x7>;
                            irq-gpios = <0x3d 0x15 0x7>;
                            compatible = "microchip,wilc1000", "microchip,wilc3000";
                            reg = <0x0>;
                            status = "okay";
                    };
            };
```

Then I compilated the `am335x-boneblack.dts` file to `am335x-boneblack.dtb` and placed it in `/boot/dtbs/4.14.71-ti-r80/` replacing the old file. After rebboting the board, I tried to verify if the mofification had been done using the command

```
dtc -I fs /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ |less
```

but I didn't find the modification I've made. Is `am335x-boneblack.dtb` the right file that is used to build the device tree ?

Comment: *"I've added some code to the am33xx.dtsi"* --  No, that's the wrong file to modify.  That **.dtsi** file  describes the common properties for a group of SoCs.  You're not making at changes at the SoC level, so don't modify such **.dtsi** files.  The SPI device you are using is added to your board, so you should be modifying the board file, i.e. the top-level **.dts** file.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks, I modified the BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dtbo, wich I use in uEnv.txt, and it worked.